# How to use first query results in next query or first dataframe results use in next data frame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, caching, pyspark

I am very new to spark and trying to get results from the first query and use that in the next query. But getting error

```
%pyspark
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import *

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "adventure", table_name = "employee")

empDF = datasource0.toDF().where("age=40 and dept=10")
empDF.createOrReplaceTempView("empDF")

datasource1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "adventure", table_name = "dept")
deptDF = datasource1.toDF()
deptDF.createOrReplaceTempView("deptDF")

queryDF = sqlContext.sql("select * rom empDF e join deptDF d on e.id = d.id and d.manag=5")

datasource2 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "adventure", table_name = "salary")
salDF = datasource2.toDF()
salDF.createOrReplaceTempView("salDF")
```

Now I want to join queryDF and salDF but it is giving me error saying query not found. how do i save the results of the first query to the table so I can use it in the second query?

```
finaDF = sqlContext.sql("select * rom queryDF e join salDF d on e.id = d.id").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that directly in python using pyspark [join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=join#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join)

In your case that'd be:

```
finaDF = deptDF.join(salDF, "id")
```

Comment: I think if I am joining the table on just id it should work. But I have a few more conditions and subquery in that query for example

Comment: finaDF = sqlContext.sql("select a,b,c,case stmt,d from (select e.* , case stmt from queryDF e join salDF d on e.id = d.id")